# Running Matlab code in Textmate

Tags: matlab, terminal, textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I am having difficulties executing Matlab code in the Terminal using the matlab.tmbundle for TextMate... Spawning Matlab works fine as well as running code directly from the terminal but it seems that the code is getting lost when I attempt to run anything from TextMate.

When I "Execute in MATLAB", the running Matlab instance simply returns a new line (ie: `>>` in the Terminal). I assume there is an issue in the above command. Is it possible I don't have access to `$TM_FILE_PATH`?

I've looked everywhere for a solution but can't seem to find one. Thanks!

Comment: So a friend of mine found a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684920/how-can-i-send-selected-text-or-a-line-in-textmate2-to-r-running-on-terminal). The solution is for R in the terminal but works fine if you simply change the source in tm to source.matlab (rather than source.r).